# On hover over any element – remove class from whatever element has that class

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseover, removeclass

I have several anchor tags inside a container.

This jQuery snippet selects one of those anchor tags, and adds a class to them:

```
$("#container").find("a").eq(random).addClass("active");
```

I want that class to be removed from whichever anchor tag currently has it, when a user hovers the cursor over any of the anchor tags inside the container.

**Question:** What's the jQuery code for: "on hover over any of anchor tags inside the `#container`, remove `.active` class from whichever of the anchor tags in the container currently has it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want just:

```
$("#container a").hover(function() {
    $("#container a.active").removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: You think correctly, @roasted, and thank you very much! That's exactly what I've been looking for. The only thing is, I just added it to the page I'm working on, and it revealed an additional challenge. May I ask you to take a look at a separate question I am about to write?

Comment: Could you take a look at another question, @roasted ? It's in continuation of the one you just helped me with. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713676/add-class-when-hovered-not-over-any-of-the-group-of-elements

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jQuery Hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) handler

```
$("container a.active").hover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

Alternatively, you can also use mouseenter handler

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b84t5/

Comment: Doesn't it say: "when you hover over the anchor tag that currently has the .active class, remove the active class", @c.P.u1 - am I right?

Comment: It says when you hover over a <a> with class active, it will remove its "active" class

Comment: Thanks, @c.P.u.1 – my question was, "when you hover over any of the links inside the container", not just the active one. Roasted gave the answer I was looking for. I'd still vote up your answer, but my reputation is too small to be able to vote up.

Comment: No problem @Piano bro, I understood your question after roasted posted the answer.

Comment: May I ask you to take a look at another (related) question, please, @c.P.u.1 ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713676/add-class-when-hovered-not-over-any-of-the-group-of-elements