# Add class when hovered NOT over any of the group of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, addclass

I have a bunch of anchor tags inside a `#container`. I am selecting a random anchor tag with jQuery and adding an `.active` class to it.

Then, when a user hovers over any of these anchor tags, the .active class gets removed from the one that currently has it:

```
$("#container").find("a").eq(random).addClass("active"); 
$("#container a").hover(function() {
    $("container a.active").removeClass("active");
});
```

I want to add one more thing to this. If a user hovers NOT over any of the links inside the `#container`, I want to add the `.active` class again to any random anchor tag inside the `#container`. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: "If a user hovers NOT over any of the links inside the #container" I cannot understand this sentence

Comment: It means, @roasted that as long as the user hovers over any of the anchor tags, no class should be added to any of the anchor tags. So if the user simply moves the mouse from one anchor tag to the other, .active class should not be added.  But if a user moves the cursor off the anchor tag and not onto the other anchor tag, .active class should be added to any randomly chosen anchor tag inside the #container.

Comment: You should seriously think about to add a jsfiddle for this kind of question. This would save time to everybody, even for you

Comment: I just created one, @roasted. Thank you for the suggestion! Could you please take a look – I may have made a mistake with it, but it doesn't seem to be doing what it should: http://jsfiddle.net/yJVKj/3/

Comment: FYI, I updated my answer to include working version of you [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/gPTzZ/), and just so you know, till i fiddleed it, I didn't realize I was missing a "#" on one line, so the original answer didn't work, but does now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#container").find("a").eq(random).addClass("active"); 
$("#container a").hover(function() {
    $("container a.active").removeClass("active");
},
function(e) {
    $("#container").find("a").eq(random).addClass("active");
});
```

The second handler is "hover out", though it would probably work better with something like:

```
//  begin working on parent container
//  .mouseleave allows us to know exactly,
//      on a single event fire,
//      when mouse has left the parent container
$("#container").on("mouseleave", function(e) {
    //  of course, add class to random anchor
    $(this).find("a").eq(random).addClass("active");
})  //  jQuery Chaining allows us to then move on forward to the a tags
.find("a").hover(function() {   //  upon hover, remove ALL instances of "active" class
    $("#container a.active").removeClass("active");
})  //  our returned Object is the same as "$("#container").find("a")"
.eq(random).addClass("active");
```

## jsFiddle

More About:

- [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

  - Don't forget, this method has up to **2** handlers!
- [.mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

  - See Also: [mouseleave vs](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1805-jQuery-Events-MouseOver-MouseOut-vs-MouseEnter-MouseLeave.htm)
- [jQuery Chaining](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/)

Comment: @CSL lol, not yet, i just kinda through it up there, but i'm editing it, i'll up you too :P

Comment: For some reason, @SpYk3hh, every now and then when I move the cursor off the links, no class gets added?

Comment: @Piano I'm not seeing that issue, tho I did just make a [tweek based on your tweek](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/gPTzZ/), lol

Comment: @Piano I do see where if you move the mouse up and down real fast, sometimes 2 links end up active, though, I would see this as being an issue with jsFiddle and the iFrame there, not an issue that would appear on an actual page

Comment: I see the issue: I think when the mouse is out of #container, no class gets assigned? Is it possible, @SpYk3HH?

Comment: @Piano its not possible if it was a full page, however, again, I think some issues may reside with the fact of it being in an i frame. ***Unless*** you're reffering to the fact that the mouse is hovered in container but not on a link, then yes, no class is added, but that was as per your code. You could conquer this making the container "inline-block" or by changing the expected functionality via the code. Is that a change you want? I updated the original again to have a better random function.

Comment: @Piano BTW, If you really want to see how something in a jsFiddle would act in "full page environment", simple add "/show" to the end of the url, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/gPTzZ/show/ ... I just realized who this is! Welcome back! lol

Comment: @Piano I see, so this is what you were talking about with the instrument links, play with it for a few mins, open a chat, i'ma go do something, when i get back we'll tackle this!

Comment: Thank you, @SpYk3HH – I got some of my "reputation" removed for asking too many stupid questions, would need another 8 points before I can open a chat, damn it.

Comment: @Piano i see that, bummer, it wont even let me start chat with you, oh well, lets do this!

Comment: How about, I mark your answer as accepted and you vote up a couple of my stupid questions as interesting – so I could open a chatroom, SpYk3HH? Probably not very ethical to vote up mine, but could simplify things. :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30496/discussion-between-spyk3hh-and-piano)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by using mouseenter and mouseleave instead of hover

```
$("#container").find("a").eq(random).addClass("active"); 
$("#container a").mouseenter(function() {
     $("container a.active").removeClass("active");
});
$("#container a").mouseleave(function() {
     $("#container").find("a").eq(random).addClass("active"); 
});
```

Comment: Could you take a look at this JSFiddle please, @CSL: http://jsfiddle.net/yJVKj/5/ somehow it's not doing what it should, wvwn though everything in code tells me it has to be correct...

Comment: @Piano corrected you were missing a # on the container selector [jsfiddle.net/yJVKj/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/yJVKj/11/) plus you need to regenerate the random number in the mouseleave - check the fiddle it is working now.